# How to load all the products regardless of the status of products?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using following code to get all the products assigned to a category.

```
    $category = 26;
    $productcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $productcollection = $productcollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category),true);
    $productcollection = $productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

But I am getting only the enabled product.All the products in this category are of configurable type.

I want all the products whether the product is enabled or disabled.

Comment: You need this on frontend or backend?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Magento: Display disabled products on frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281442/magento-display-disabled-products-on-frontend)

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
              ->getProductCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
```

Answer (score 0):

To load all the products whether enabled or disabled you have to use the table catalog_product_entity instead of the flat table.
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
Here the getCollection() function fetches the data from the flat table.
So there are two work around for this:

1. From the magento admin panel switch of the use of flat tables. Then run the script. This will give you the entire collection.

OR

2. Direct sql query two fetch products from catalog_product_entity table.